# What happens to malloc variable in a function?

Tags: c

Assume I create a variable inside a function by using `malloc`:

```
int f() 
{
 int* i=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
 /* ... */
}
```

Where is variable `i` located? In heap or in function `f()` stack?

Comment: You don't create variables using `malloc`. You allocate memory with it.

Comment: You are not "creating a variable inside a function" with your `malloc`. Your variable `i` and your `malloc`-ed memory have no relation to each other whatsoever, aside from the fact that `i` happens to point to that memory initially.

Comment: in C, the returned type from the heap memory allocation functions is `void*` and can be assigned to any other pointer,  casting the returned type has no effect, just clutters the code and will be a problem when maintaining the code.  I.E. do not cast the returned value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to use `p` instead of `i`, because variables named `i` are most often integers.

```
void function(void) {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
}
```

There are two things here: `p` and `*p` with the following relationship:

```
  stack          heap
│   ... │     │   ... │
┢━━━━━━━┪     ┢━━━━━━━┪
┃     p ┃ ──→ ┃    *p ┃
┡━━━━━━━┩     ┡━━━━━━━┩
│   ... │     │   ... │
```

Once you return from the function, `p` is gone.  However, `*p` will remain allocated until you call `free()`.  Forgetting to call `free()` means you have a "memory leak", because `*p` will stick around forever even though you can't use it (because `p` is gone).

**Note:** `p` is not necessarily on the stack, but you can pretend that it is.  It could be in a register or optimized out entirely.  It can even move around on the stack.  The whole concepts of "stack" and "heap" are technically implementation-specific anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For most systems the answer by @Dietrich Epp covers the question. For completeness I like to add:

There is no general way to say where/how variables are stored. It is not part of the standard. It depends on your specific system.

There is no such thing as stack and heap in `c`. The concepts are implementation details which are system specific.

The standard (ISO/IEC 9899) specifies "storage duration" like this:

> 6.2.4 An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There are three storage
>   durations: static, automatic, and allocated.

and the standard describes the associated rules but the standard doesn't care how it is implemented.

Use of `stack` and `heap` are common for most implementations but it is not a requirement in any way.

Comment: The question asks "where is `i`?" and saying that the C standard doesn't answer the question doesn't answer the question.  (Also, a fourth storage duration was introduced in C11, with implementations dating long before the standard's release.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think it does because it is the only correct answer - you just don't know without explicit mentioning the used implementation.  Saying that it is on stack or anywhere else, is however a mistake. Just as much as it is a mistake to pretend that `c` has stack and heap.

Comment: Stack Overflow can be a hostile experience for inexperienced developers.  Answering questions in a strictly-technically-correct is a major factor in that hostility.  Consider what information the question asker might want to learn from the answer, and whether your question brings the asker closer to that knowledge, or whether it shows off your knowledge of the C standard.

Comment: Also, if you are going to cite the C standard, I insist that you mention the version of the C standard that you are citing.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Giving an incorrect answer - just to be polite - is IMO not the way to go. I don't think it is hostile to tell OP that there is a basic misunderstanding in OPs question. Here OP obviously thinks that heap and stack is a part of `c`. Do you really think we should let OP go on with that misunderstanding?

Comment: Please join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125806/40061968

Answer (score 2):

The variable is *i. It is there with our without malloc. It is a pointer.

malloc returns the start-address of an allocated memory in the heap. And the = assigns this address to your pointer.

Say i = NULL you allign 0 to this pointer or you can also assign whatever to it (e.g. 4711). But if you access it by reading or writhing at the memory the address points to and it is not in your address-area you get an segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a local variable so the compiler may allocate stack storage for it but this depends on the scenario, its also possible in some simple use cases that the compiler/optimizer can avoid the stack and just use a register.

This variable, `i`, contains a numeric value corresponding to the address of a dynamic allocation of an int sized space.